# Substring an element value whith &amp; in xsl

Tags: xslt, substring, saxon

I'm trying to supstring a string value with xslt.

```
<element><value>Value of element</value></element>

<element><xsl:value-of select="substring(element/value,1,40)"/></element>
```

This works great when there is no & in the value. In my case the value is

```
<element><value>Company ABC GmbH &amp; Co.</value></element>
```

and the substring is not working and the value longer than 40.

I'm using xslt 2.0 and Saxon.

Comment: Can you be more precise, rather than just say "it is not working"? Are you getting an error, for example, or just not getting your expected results? It would really help alot if you showed an example of more than 40 characters, together with your expected output, and the output you are actually getting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is written in XML as

```
<value>Company ABC GmbH &amp; Co.</value>
```

then the string you are processing in XPath/XSLT is

```
Company ABC GmbH & Co.
```

which means, for example, that substring(value, 18, 4) will give you the string "& Co", which will be serialized as `"&amp; Co"`